# Representations of $SO(3)$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$

Tags: representation-theory, rotations, locally-compact-groups

So my professor has given me the problem of examining the representations of $SO(3)$ in $V = \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$. The thing is that he's now gone away for a conference trip, and I have absolutely no idea where to start.

I don't have a super solid background in representation theory; I've read the first part of Serre's *Linear Representations of Finite Groups*, and I know the basic concepts of compact groups and the Haar measure. To me this doesn't seem like enough in order to tackle this problem, but he insists that it is.

Is it possible for someone to help me get started? As noted earlier, I'm totally lost...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at Fulton and Harris's Representation Theory book?  It starts with Lie Algebra representations, and has a couple of long examples with $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and $\mathfrak{su}(3)$.  Might be more what you need.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yeah I've looked at it, and it seems really interesting, but according to my professor I don't need more than what I already know. And my goal isn't to find all irreps of $SO(3)$, but rather to just study this specific case.

Comment: I dunno, then, [Wikipedia?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SU(2))